# CoreNLP to extract street number and zip codes from tweets

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am using CoreNLP (Stanford) and Java to extract the mention of locations from tweets. I can extract information like "Shirley Street Port Arthur TX". However, I cannot extract the street number or Zip code. In this case, it should have been "2333 Shirley Street Port Arthur TX".

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TokensRegexAnnotator to write rules to identify patterns such as addresses.

There is more detailed documentation about how to write the rules here:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.html